# How to run multiple dd commands in background & see status?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, command-line, dd

I want to run multiple dd commands in background, but be able to see the status.

I have the following `script.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for drive in $@
do
  echo "Wiping $drive"
  dd if=/dev/zero of=$drive status=progress &
done
wait
echo "Done."
```

Which results in the following output:

```
$ sudo bash ./script.sh /dev/sda /dev/sdb
Wiping /dev/sda
Wiping /dev/sdb
288788992 bytes (289 MB, 275 MiB) copied, 10 s, 28.9 MB/s 14404864 bytes (114 MB, 109 MiB) copied, 4 s, 28.6 MB/s
```

Is there any way how to output the respective dd statuses below the drive paths? For example:

```
$ sudo bash ./script.sh /dev/sda /dev/sdb
Wiping /dev/sda
288788992 bytes (289 MB, 275 MiB) copied, 10 s, 28.9 MB/s
Wiping /dev/sdb
14404864 bytes (114 MB, 109 MiB) copied, 4 s, 28.6 MB/s
```

I tried various redirects, named pipes etc. but wasn't able to achieve such (or similar) output.

---

I tried the coprocesses approach which seems to be the way to go, but now I'm unable to make it work with the for cycle.

This works fine:

```bash
coproc dd_sda { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda status=progress 2>&1; }
echo "sda PID: $dd_sda_PID"
coproc dd_sdb { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb status=progress 2>&1; }
echo "sdb PID: $dd_sdb_PID"
```

```
sda PID: 12494
./wipe.sh: line 86: warning: execute_coproc: coproc [12494:dd_sda] still exists
sdb PID: 12496
```

However this:

```bash
for drive in sda sdb
do
  coproc_name=dd_${drive}
  coproc $coproc_name { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/$drive status=progress 2>&1; }
  pid_var="${coproc_name}_PID"
  echo "$drive PID: ${!pid_var}"
done
```

doesn't work for the second coprocess:

```
sda PID: 12759
./wipe.sh: line 39: warning: execute_coproc: coproc [12759:dd_sda] still exists
sdb PID:
```

When hardcoding the name using if condition, it also works:

```bash
for drive in sda sdb
do
  coproc_name=dd_${drive}
  if [[ "$drive" == 'sda' ]]
  then
    coproc dd_sda { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/$drive status=progress 2>&1; }
  elif [[ "$drive" == 'sdb' ]]
  then
    coproc dd_sdb { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/$drive status=progress 2>&1; }
  fi
  pid_var="${coproc_name}_PID"
  echo "$drive PID: ${!pid_var}"
done
```

```
sda PID: 12998
./wipe.sh: line 39: warning: execute_coproc: coproc [12998:dd_sda] still exists
sdb PID: 13000
```

Comment: Some `dd` implementations will emit a status report when you send them a particular signal (IIRC `SIGUSR1`, but check the man page).

Comment: Redirect the output of each `dd` command to a file. At the end, print all the files.

Comment: @markp-fuso Sorry, I didn't save the code. However, the main issue was that I couldn't find a way how to print two FIFOs simultaneously. When using `cat` command, it printed just the first and kept running until it finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my final solution, massively inspired by @Diego Torres Milano (thanks again).

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

drives=$@
number_of_drives=$#
drives_to_wipe=($drives)

stripped_drive_path() {
  echo $1 | awk -F/ '{ print $3 }'
}

wipe() {
  echo "Filling \`$1\` drive with zeros:"
  dd if=/dev/zero of=$1 status=progress 2>&1
}

echo "Total number of drives: $number_of_drives"

# Wipe the drives in parallel

iteration=1
for drive in $drives; do
  drive_name=$(stripped_drive_path $drive)
  coproc_name=dd_${drive_name}
  eval coproc $coproc_name "{ wipe $drive; }"
  if [[ "$iteration" == 1 ]]; then
    echo 'Feel free to ignore the following warnings'
  fi
  ((iteration++))
done

# Display the progress

iteration=1
# Run until all drives are wiped
while [[ ${#drives_to_wipe[@]} > 0 ]]; do
  for drive in $drives; do
    drive_name=$(stripped_drive_path $drive)
    coproc_name=dd_${drive_name}

    # Move one line below the "Filling drive with zeros" message
    if [[ $iteration > 1 ]]; then
      tput cud 1
    fi

    # Read the drive's current status from the coprocess
    if read -r -d $'\r' -u ${!coproc_name[0]} line &> /dev/null; then
      tput el # Clear line
      echo -e "$line\r\n"
    else
      # Remove the finished drive from the list
      for i in ${!drives_to_wipe[@]}; do
        if [ "${drives_to_wipe[$i]}" == "$drive" ]; then
          unset drives_to_wipe[$i]
        fi
      done
      tput el # Clear line
      echo -e "$(($number_of_drives - ${#drives_to_wipe[@]}))/$number_of_drives done!\r\n"
    fi

    # Move back one line up
    if [[ $iteration > 1 ]]; then
      tput cuu 1
    fi

  done

  # Move two lines up for each drive
  if [[ ${#drives_to_wipe[@]} > 0 ]]; then
    tput cuu $(($number_of_drives * 2))
  fi

  ((iteration++))
done

echo "All drives ($number_of_drives) wiped."
```

Which results in such output:

```
$ sudo bash ./script.sh /dev/sda /dev/sdb
Total number of drives: 2
Feel free to ignore the following warnings
./wipe.sh: line 24: warning: execute_coproc: coproc [85994:dd_sda] still exists
Filling `/dev/sda` drive with zeros:
1/2 done!
Filling `/dev/sdb` drive with zeros:
2/2 done!
All drives (2) wiped.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using coprocesses you can do something like this

```
#! /bin/bash

coproc DD1 { dd if=/dev/zero of=$drive1 status=progress 2>&1; }
coproc DD2 { dd if=/dev/zero of=$drive2 status=progress 2>&1; }
coproc DD3 { dd if=/dev/zero of=$drive3 status=progress 2>&1; }

el=$(tput el)
cuu1=$(tput cuu1)

IFS=
while :
do
    for n in {1..3}
    do
        v="DD$n"
        if read -r -d $'\r' -u ${!v[0]} line
        then
            printf '%s%s: %s\r\n' "$el" "$v" "$line"
        else
            printf '%s: Done\r\n' "$el" "$v"
        fi
    done
    for n in {1..3}
    do
        printf '%s' "$cuu1"
    done
done
```

my `dd` does not have `status` so I'm assuming `dd` adds a `\r` instead of `\n`.

#### edit

for loop (*unfortunately eval seems to be the only option, don't know why `coproc` is not take the name from a variable though*)

```
for n in {1..3}
do
    eval coproc "DD${n}" "{ dd if=/dev/zero of=\$drive$n status=progress 2>&1; }"
done
```

Comment: Awesome, coprocesses are the way to go, thanks! Just getting `warning: execute_coproc: coproc still exists` error immediately after starting.

Comment: Yes, just a warning, it seems there's no way of suppressing it

Comment: I see. However I'm not able to make it work with the for cycle when defining coprocesses. Please see updated question above.

Comment: Thanks, using eval works. Really weird the variable doesn't.

Comment: I have it. Your solution really helped although it needed a bit tweaking so that the while loop ends gracefully. Posting my final solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the status of each `dd` to a file, and print those files repeatedly while clearing the old output.

`dd status=progress` from GNU coreutils prints its status to stderr, so use `2>` to redirect the status info.
The status is updated by overwriting the current line with `\r` followed by the new status. Since `\r` only works for single lines, updating four different lines needs terminal control sequences, e.g. [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) which can be printed conveniently using commands like `clear` and `tput`.

```
outfile_prefix=/tmp/wipe-status-$$-
for drive in "$@"; do
  (
    echo "Wiping $drive"
    # dummy-version for testing ...
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1 count=5M status=progress 2>&1
    # ... if you are happy with the output, replace it with
    # dd if=/dev/zero of="$drive" status=progress 2>&1
  ) > "$outfile_prefix$BASHPID" &
done

clear -x  # clear the currently visible screen
while             # do-while loop
  tput home                  # move cursor to top left
  sed '' "$outfile_prefix"*  # print files like `cat`, but with \n at the end
  jobs %% &> /dev/null       # while jobs are running
do
  sleep 1
done

rm "$outfile_prefix"*
```

Above code is inefficient if you are wiping many big or slow drives, because the status files keep growing (even though they *seem* to contain only one line) and we keep printing those growing files over and over again.

If you run into problems, try to increase the sleep time. Maybe `sed 's/.*\r//'` instead of `sed ''` can speed things up. `tail -c100` would definitively help, but inserts the temp. file names into the output.

The correct way to handle situation would be ...

- Use fifos instead of files (see `mkfifo` command).
- Remove the `status=progress` and periodically ...

  - Call `kill -s USR1` for all* running `dd` jobs,
    which causes them to print a single status line.
  - Update some internal status array by reading the fifos*.
  - Print all statuses from the array.

* At some point, only a few `dd` jobs will run while others already finished and closed their fifos, which complicates that process a bit. This is the main reason I sticked with files for this answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, writing to files was something I wanted to avoid because of the reasons you describe. I was trying to work with FIFOs but then I wasn't able to read multiple statuses from them: the `cat` command printed just one FIFO and kept open until it finishes.